# Learning material on information visualization

Tags: information-retrieval

If somebody with a computer science background wants to learn about information visualization, again from a computer science perspective, which will be the best learning material for him?

A textbook will be preferred but any other tutorial or something similar is also welcome.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking here.  What is information visualization "from a computer science perspective"?

Comment: @BenI. Something like the material presented in [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=614508), in a more elaborate manner.